# function to generate random variables based on a condition

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I would like to generate two random variables based on a third variable.

So there would be a certain predefined standard normal variable 'c' and I would generate variables a and b such that c=a-b where a,b are all normally distributed. So if c has a mean of mu_c and a standard deviavtion of sd_c, a and b have means mu_a and mu_b and sds sd_a and sd_b respectively, then mu_c=mu_a-mu_b and we have sd_c = sd_a+sd_b. I apologize for my lack of code but I am confused on hwo to implement this variable generation..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do with code below. I do not understand why do you need mean and standard deviation of a and b values but you can control with written code below.

```
a=rnorm(100)
b=rnorm(100)
mu_a=mean(a,na.RM=TRUE)
sd_a=sd(a,na.RM=TRUE)
mu_b=mean(b,na.RM=TRUE)
sd_b=sd(b,na.RM=TRUE)

mu_c=mu_a-mu_b
sd_c=sd_a+_sd_b
c=a-b
mu_c2=mean(c,na.RM=TRUE)
sd_c2=sd(c,na.RM=TRUE)
```